# More than two values in array_combine string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add an extra array in to my array_combine function and I get the following error when more than two values have been added:

> [24-Oct-2017 12:18:18 UTC] PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /manage/add-users-to-courses.php on line 61

My working code:

```
$stmtcd = "SELECT id, course_title FROM distributor_course_settings WHERE distributor = ? AND active = 'Y' AND price NOT LIKE '0.00'";
$stmtcd = $conn->prepare($stmtcd);
$stmtcd->bind_param('s', $distributor);
$stmtcd->execute();
$stmtcd->bind_result($id, $course_title);

while($stmtcd->fetch()) {
    $course_id_array[] = $id;
    $course_title_array[] = $course_title;
}

<?php
    foreach (array_combine($course_id_array, $course_title_array) as $course_id => $course_title) {
        echo '<tr style="background: #dddddd;">';
        echo '<td><h2 style="text-align: center; margin: 0;">' . $course_title . ' - ' . $price . '</h2></td>';
        echo '</tr>';

        foreach (array_combine($user_id_array, $username_array) as $user_id => $username) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="" name="" value="' . $course_id . ',' . $course_title . ',' . $price . ',' . $user_id . ',' . $username . '"> ' . $username . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Whenever I try to add 'price' to the SELECT statement and also in to the for each statement, I get the above error.

Why is this? Is there a limit to values allowed in a foreach/array_combine?

Comment: `var_dump(array_combine($course_id_array, $course_title_array))` - what do you get?

Comment: That looks like a very inefficient way to store the information you get from the database. Why don't you just store complete rows in a results array?

Comment: @jeroen it's the only way I know so it'll have to be for now.

Comment: You should really look into that `var_dump` thing if you want to get to the bottom of this…

Comment: array(2) { [1]=> string(15) "Manual Handling" [2]=> string(15) "Basic First Aid" }

Comment: As soon as I add the price value in, I get NULL...

Comment: So that probably means no row is matching, those arrays aren't getting created at all, you're trying to combine two `null` values and you should be seeing a warning about that.

Comment: The error log is showing: array_combine() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given ...

Comment: @deceze how can no row match? I'm pulling 3 columns from 2 rows in my database, both in the same table? There is a definite match.

Comment: You're not passing 3 parameters, this code cannot produce that error.

Comment: And I don't know what rows are matching. The fact is that *if* no rows are matching, the `$course_*_array` variables won't be created (as far as I can see) which would explain that you get `null`. And/or you have the same problem the second time you use `array_combine`. I don't know which line that error is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

## Follow good coding standards and [best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices)

While "best practices" are wide ranging, overwhelmingly numerous, and filled with differing opinions, they're important and *usually* all agree. In your case, you should [initialize variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) (see Example1).

#### PHP [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) expects Array

*More than expects, array_combine **requires** that all arguments are arrays.* Thus, initialize those variables as empty arrays.

```
$course_id_array = [];
$course_title_array = [];
$user_id_array = [];
$username_array = [];

while($stmtcd->fetch()) {
    $course_id_array[] = $id;
    $course_title_array[] = $course_title;
}
```

#### Don't break your data.

In your code, you separate the data's `ID` and the data into different arrays, only to combine them again in order to loop through them. Create the array properly to begin with, and your code will be *much* cleaner.

```
$courses = [];
while($stmtcd->fetch()) {
    $courses[$id] = $course_title;
}

foreach($courses as $course_id => $course_title) {
    // your code here
}
```

#### Use objects to make life easier

While building everything procedural is simpler at first, OOP will make life easier.

```
// build an object for your Course
Class Course
{
    public $id, $title, $price;

    public function __construct($title, $id = 0)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}

// Build an object for your db conn and queries
// Note: in a larger app, DB conn, and specific SQL commands, should be built in different objects, Like:
//     $dbo = new DBO($conn);
//     $courseTools = new CourseDBTools($dbo);
//     $course = $courseTools->getOneMatchingCourse([args]);
Class DBO
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function getCoursesByDistrubutor($distributor)
    {
        $title = '';
        $id = 0;
        $price = 99;
        $stmtcd = "SELECT id, course_title, price FROM distributor_course_settings WHERE distributor = ? AND active = 'Y' AND price NOT LIKE '0.00'";
        $stmtcd = $this->conn->prepare($stmtcd);
        $stmtcd->bind_param('s', $distributor);
        $stmtcd->execute();
        $stmtcd->bind_result($id, $title, $price);

        while($stmtcd->fetch()) {
            $course = new Course($title, $id);
            $course->price = $price;
            yield $course;
        }
    }
}

// Then your actual code becomes clean and simple
$distributor = 'ABC';
$conn = null; //set it, 
$dbo = new DBO($conn);

foreach ($dbo->getCoursesByDistrubutor($distributor) as $course) {
    echo $course->title . ' - ' . $course->price;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simpler.  Change the two loops to these two:

```
while($stmtcd->fetch()) {
    $titles[$id] = $course_title;
}
foreach ($titles as $course_id => $course_title) { ... }
```

If you later need only the ids or only the titles (without the ids), see `array_keys($title)` and `array_values($titles)`.